# WordPress add_rewrite_rule not working with page_on_front

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I am using the following code to rewrite "example.com?my_var=test" to "example.com/my_var/test":

```
function my_query_vars($vars)
{
    $vars[] = 'my_var';
    return $vars;
}

function my_rewrite()
{
    add_filter('query_vars', 'my_query_vars');
    add_rewrite_tag('%my_var%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^my_var/(.+)/?$', 'index.php?page_id=16&my_var=$matches[1]', 'top');
}

add_action('init', 'my_rewrite');
```

This only works, if the page with id 16 is not set as "page_on_front" in the WordPress settings.

- "page_on_front" = whatever --> above code works
- "page_on_front" = 16 --> "example.com/my_var/test" redirects to "example.com"

Do you have an idea why this is happening?

thanks a lot,
Jan

**EDIT**

I disabled the redirect with this code and it seems to work just fine:

```
function disable_redirect($redirect_url, $requested_url)
{
    if ( get_query_var( 'my_var' ) )
    {
        return '';
    }
    return $redirect_url;
}

function my_query_vars($vars)
{
    $vars[] = 'my_var';
    return $vars;
}

function my_rewrite()
{    
    add_filter('redirect_canonical', 'disable_redirect', 10, 2);
    add_filter('query_vars', 'my_query_vars');
    add_rewrite_tag('%my_var%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^my_var/(.+)/?$', 'index.php?page_id=16&my_var=$matches[1]', 'top');
}

add_action('init', 'my_rewrite');
```

Do you think this is a good solution?
Is there a better way to disable the redirect?